# Modern Team Site document library page in SP2019 does not show Exit classic experience option

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am working with SharePoint on prem 2019 and have a team site created in modern experience where several document libraries have been added. 
When site is accessed and document library link is clicked from quick launch, it opens up in modern UI. Once return to classic sharepoint is clicked, it takes to the classic experience. Once on the classic UI page, I do not see 'Exit Classic experience' link on the lower bottom left to go back to modern ui at all.

What could be the cause of this, can someone please assist, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, in that I'm working with SP2019 and attempting to migrate an old farm. I can't tell you *why* it's happening, or whether (or not) libraries in this state are supposed to have a link, but you can change it in "library settings", right at the bottom of the "Advanced Settings" page. [![The "List experience" section in "Advanced Settings"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkcpx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkcpx.png)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to delete a `spInu`cookie via the Chrome Dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Denis, appreciate it. I located the cookie you mentioned, deleted it as well but it comes back with the page load again, I still don't see exit classic experience option